# My stove works, but the oven sparks without lighting

Tags: valve, oven

I have an old Whirlpool Accubake model wfg361lvs.

We've had the oven for about two years. The oven part has never worked for us, but the stove does. I'm finally taking the time to troubleshoot the thing.

If I try to set the oven to either bake or broil I just get repeated clicks with no ignition or gas flow. It doesn't use a heated coil igniter. It's just a spark ignite.

Basic research tells me this is an issue with either the igniter or the safety valve.

I notice there is some possible discoloration on the igniter, so I scrub it with steel wool. I measure the current through the igniter while it clicks, and it reads about 3A, right about where it should be.

I go on to test the safety valve. I find [this](https://www.justanswer.com/appliance/avvkq-problem-whirlpool-gas-range-model-wfg361lvs.html) post discussing testing the safety valve on this model oven, which says the resistance between terminals on the valve should be 215ohm +- 10%. I measure 155 between each pair. This is a little on the low side, but not a lot. I'm beginning to think the safety valve is the issue.

However, while testing the valve, I had foolishly forgotten to unplug the oven. This resulted in a rather painful shock to my right hand. Afterward when I retested the igniter it still read 3A along the wire leading into it, but only 1.5A along the igniter itself. Could I have somehow ruined the igniter when I shocked myself?

Overall, my gut says I need to replace both the igniter and the safety valve. I wanted to ask what others thought, as the replacements will cost several times what we paid for the oven. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: 155 ohm isn't a "little low". 215 - 10% is 193ohm. 155 ohm is only 72% (+/- 28% from spec). Good chance that's your problem.

Comment: Though I practice DIY, on something as essential to safety as a gas supply valve, I'd suggest calling someone licensed to fix it. Yes, labor is expensive -- but so are hospital bills and funerals.

Comment: Depending on the age(older is better), the short you experience could have damage other parts(electronics) in the stove/oven.  If those parts cost that much, I would need a good think about replacing them instead of the stove.